# What services are included in an AWS Educate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am looking to apply for [AWS Educate](https://aws.amazon.com/education/awseducate/apply/). I know that it offers a limited subset of services, but I cannot find anywhere that the subset is listed.

What AWS services are supported by the AWS Educate program? Specifically are Lex, AIM, and Lambda, supported?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not sales support for Amazon

Comment: I would argue that isn't a valid reason to not allow a question as that could be a reason to not allow any question.

Comment: There is a series of [meta] posts explaining this in more detail. Perhaps start at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company and note that this is part of the site's FAQ.

Comment: Which program are you applying for? Are you an accredited school or university (e.g. you have a .edu domain)? There are multiple programs available. Getting into AWS Educate is difficult except for students. I would apply and see what you are approved for.

Comment: Where did you see that it only offers subset of services? I believe you have same set of services available as any other "non-gov" account. You are only limited to AWS credit.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Comment: That is what is confusing, "only limited to aws credit" I'm not sure what this means. There is lots of information that sound like it is only a limited subset of aws. I cannot find any specific details. I have reached out to aws directly but I haven't heard anything confirming what service is available. I'll be sure to answer this question if/when I get a response. I was hoping someone with an educate account could fill me in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of February 10, 2017 (the latest info as of this answer) this is the [list of supported AWS Educate Starter & Student Services](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf).

Lambda is supported but, AIM, and Lex, are not supported.